# Intl.NumberFormat#format maximum integer value

Tags: javascript, internationalization, number-formatting, ecmascript-intl

In [ECMAScript Internationalization API 1.0 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-11.1), `NumberFormat` object has a `format` function which takes in a value and formats the number according to `NumberFormat` object.

**What is the maximum value [`NumberFormat#format`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/format) function can digest?**

In Chrome, and Firefox running below:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat().format(1111111111111111);
// => "1,111,111,111,111,110"
//                         ^
//                     16th digit
```

It seems that anything after 15th digit is converted to `0`. I had a quick look at the spec, but couldn't figure out why. Does anyone know why?

Maybe because the above ES5 spec follows IEEE 754 specification? Can't think of anything else…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ES5 spec follows IEEE 754 specification

And the ECMAScript Intl API specification refers to ES5 spec for base types.